# wp alchemy multiple image uploader output images to template

Tags: loop, pages, templates, list, wpalchemy

I am using wp alchemy to add a custom metabox to my site with multiple image uploader option. This part is working fine, but I have no Idea how to go about outputting the image links to my template. I am hoping to output as a unordered list.

setup.php file

```
<?php

include_once WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/wpalchemy/MetaBox.php';
include_once WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/wpalchemy/MediaAccess.php';

// include css to help style our custom meta boxes
add_action( 'init', 'my_metabox_styles' );

function my_metabox_styles()
{
    if ( is_admin() )
    {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'wpalchemy-metabox', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/metaboxes/meta.css' );
    }
}

$wpalchemy_media_access = new WPAlchemy_MediaAccess();
```

custom-spec.php

```
<?php
$custom_mb = new WPAlchemy_MetaBox(array
(
    'id' => '_custom_meta',
    'title' => 'Add images to home page slider',
    'template' => get_stylesheet_directory() . '/metaboxes/custom-meta.php',
    'include_template' => 'home.php'
));
?>
```

custom-meta.php

```
<?php global $wpalchemy_media_access; ?>
<div class="my_meta_control">

    <p><a href="#" class="dodelete-docs button">Remove All</a></p>

    <?php while($mb->have_fields_and_multi('docs')): ?>
    <?php $mb->the_group_open(); ?>

        <a href="#" class="dodelete button">Remove</a>

        <?php $mb->the_field('imgurl'); ?>
        <?php $wpalchemy_media_access->setGroupName('img-n'. $mb->get_the_index())->setInsertButtonLabel('Insert'); ?>

        <p>
            <?php echo $wpalchemy_media_access->getField(array('name' => $mb->get_the_name(), 'value' => $mb->get_the_value())); ?>
            <?php echo $wpalchemy_media_access->getButton(); ?>
        </p>

        <?php $mb->the_field('title'); ?>
        <label for="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>">Title</label>
        <p><input type="text" id="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" value="<?php $mb->the_value(); ?>"/></p>

    <?php $mb->the_group_close(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <p style="margin-bottom:15px; padding-top:5px;"><a href="#" class="docopy-docs button">Add</a></p>

</div>
```

functions.php file

```
include_once 'metaboxes/setup.php';

include_once 'metaboxes/custom-spec.php';
```

Comment: Did you manage to make it work ?
Can you guive us the solution
: ) thanks
yann

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any output code we can reference?

Put this in your Theme file:

```
     <img src="<?php get_the_value('imgurl'); ?>” style=”width:100px;height:100px” />
```

if you have multiple you'll have to go through a foreach loop:

```
<?php

foreach ($meta['imgurl'] as $img )
{
    echo '<a href="#" /><img src="'. $img .'" /></a>';
}
?>
```

Hope this helps, I don't really know this Metabox class, however I've used many and it seems like it would work this way.

Good luck!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. What output code are you looking for, I'm not sure what to post.

Comment: If you change the $meta['imgurl'] to $meta ['img-n'] do you get a different result when wrapped in your function?

Comment: no luck, do you mean change the $meta['imgurl'] in the loop not the function.

Comment: try: `var_dump($custom_mb->the_value('imgurl');` & `var_dump($custom_mb->the_value('img-n');` and check your Post Meta to see if it's outputting the URL inside the meta data of the post.

Comment: Im sorry what you said doesn't make any sense to me, do I just place this code in my template on its own, how Do I check my Post Meta? Do you recommend a better way to create a upload button in a custom metabox

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<?php
        global $custom_mb;

        // instead of using helper functions, you can also use ...
        $sch = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), $custom_mb->get_the_id(), TRUE);

        foreach ($sch['docs'] as $img)
        {
            echo $img['imgurl'];
        }   
?>
```

Almost worked fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "Almost work fine"?

Comment: Please explain _why_ this answer is helpful.